# How to formulate "The general Sudoku problem is in P" formally and rigorously? How to calculate then the input size?

Tags: complexity-theory, decision-problem, sudoku

We consider a partially filled starting grid, where $n^2$ is the side size of the grid, $m$ is the number of non-empty initial squares, $f$ is the function that places randomly initially the integers into the squares of the grid, the $((x_i,y_i))$ are the coordinates of the initial non-empty squares, $p_i$ are the initial integers at coordinates $((x_i,y_i))$:

"If $\forall n \ge 1~~  \exists m \in [\![1;n^2 \times n^2 ]\!]~~\exists ((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),...,(x_m,y_m)) \in \left([\![1;n^2 ]\!]^2\right)^m~~\exists (p_1,p_2,...,p_m) \in [\![1;n^2 ]\!]^m$

\begin{align*}
\exists f:[\![1;n^2]\!]^2 &\longrightarrow [\![1;n^2]\!]\\
(x,y) &\longmapsto p_i ~~ \text{if } \exists i \in [\![1;m]\!]~(x,y)=(x_i,y_i)\\
(x,y) &\longmapsto \varnothing ~~ \text{if } \forall i \in [\![1;m]\!]~(x,y) \ne (x_i,y_i)
\end{align*}

there exists a polynomial time Turing machine filling empty squares following these 3 rules:

1. Every row has every integer from 1 to $n^2$.
2. Every column has every integer from 1 to $n^2$.
3. Every square of such coordinates, for $p$ and $q \in [\![0;n-1]\!]$:

3.1 Bottom Left corner coordinates: $(pn+1,qn+1)$

3.2 Top Left corner coordinates: $(pn+1,(q+1)n)$

3.3 Top Right corner coordinates: $((p+1)n,(q+1)n)$

3.4 Bottom Right corner coordinates: $((p+1)n,qn+1)$

has every integer from 1 to $n^2$ ?"

Is this a correct formulation?

And what would be the size of the input with this formulation? Because there are three inputs: $n$,$m$, and $f$. Is it possible to reduce the number of inputs to one?

The case of an empty starting grid has also to be studied.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/53529/5038, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/162883/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).